# Can extensions be run on Chrome OS in kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

Google is deprecating Chrome apps in favor of Progressive Web Apps (PWA) or Chrome extensions. This leaves extensions as the only way to access Chrome device APIs. I'm looking for a way for my PWA to run along with a Chrome extension in kiosk mode but I'm not sure if it's possible.

The reason I need my PWA to access Chrome device APIs is to get a unique identifier per device to decide which content to display.

Comment: No, it's only for [chrome apps](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:extensions/common/manifest_handlers/kiosk_mode_info.cc;l=134;drc=151d835e9f1cdd57ca46e372bf127f74316dd4c8;bpv=1;bpt=1?sq=package:chromium).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: We're facing the same issue, so let us know if you found out a solution

Answer (score 0):

As per chromeos.dev: "Previously, Chrome Apps had extra functionality available to them in kiosk mode that is not currently supported by web apps alone. You can continue to use some of this functionality by deploying an extension with your kiosk web application."

Source: https://chromeos.dev/en/education/connecting-an-extension-from-a-kiosk-pwa

It only talks about sending a message from PWA to extension in order to execute a chrome API (like restart) but doesn't talk about how to send information back from extension to PWA. We are also stuck in the same boat- looking for a unique identifier so as to throw content on the chromebox running the PWA. Currently we use chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes to get serial number and directory device ID in kiosk mode and would need the same once we migrate to PWA. Any luck on this?

Comment: I was able to fetch deviceAttributes (serial, location, directoryId, notes) by following this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1314761